# change the static pivot to dynamic pivot sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done doing a static pivot , that mean i list the pivot column name.. ,
this is my code..

```
SELECT Date, 
ISNULL(XSP, 'X')as XSP,
ISNULL(BSR, 'X')as BSR,
ISNULL(BPT, 'X')as BPT,
ISNULL(XPW, 'X')as XPW,
ISNULL(IPH, 'X')as IPH,
ISNULL(XTH, 'X')as XTH,
ISNULL(TGG, 'X')as TGG,
ISNULL(XKG, 'X')as XKG,
ISNULL(XKM, 'X')as XKM,
ISNULL(XLG, 'X')as XLG,
ISNULL(KBR, 'X')as KBR,
ISNULL(KUA, 'X')as KUA,
ISNULL(LGK, 'X')as LGK,
ISNULL(MKZ, 'X')as MKZ,
ISNULL(PEN, 'X')as PEN,
ISNULL(XGM, 'X')as XGM,
ISNULL(JHB, 'X')as JHB,
ISNULL(XBN, 'X')as XBN,
ISNULL(STW, 'X')as STW,
ISNULL(TIN, 'X')as TIN,
ISNULL(MUA, 'X')as MUA
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_status
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
Union 
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
Union
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date 
FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
And date IS NOT NULL) AS monthlyRpt
PIVOT (MAX(status)
FOR userid IN (XSP, BSR, BPT, XPW, IPH, XTH, TGG, XKG, XKM, XLG, KBR, KUA, LGK,MKZ, PEN, XGM, JHB, XBN, STW, TIN, MUA)) AS pivottable
```

after execute all of this code it will make the output like this ,
the column include date , and all code name

[This is the output image of query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFMLm.png)

so how can i change the code to a dynamic pivot.. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes that you have a table that contains userid.
And your query would be like this:

```
   DECLARE @User AS TABLE (UserId varchar(50))
   INSERT INTO @User VALUES ('XSP'), ('BSR'), ('BPT')

   DECLARE @HeaderText nvarchar(max) 
   DECLARE @ColumnPiVot nvarchar(max)

   SELECT @ColumnPiVot = Stuff((SELECT concat(', ',td.UserId) FROM (select DISTINCT tt.UserId  
                                                         FROM @User tt ) td FOR XML PATH (''))
                         ,1,1,''),
         @HeaderText = CONCAT( N'Date, ' ,  Stuff((SELECT concat(', ISNULL(',td.UserId,',0) AS', ' ',td.UserId ) 
                                            FROM (select DISTINCT tt.UserId FROM @User tt ) td FOR XML PATH (''))
                                      ,1,1,''))
   DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(N'SELECT ' , @HeaderText,
   ' FROM
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date
         FROM edrsDB..tbl_status
         WHERE   DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
                And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
         Union 
         SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date
         FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday
         WHERE   DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
                And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
         Union
         SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date 
         FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend
         WHERE   DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
                And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
                And date IS NOT NULL
      ) AS monthlyRpt
   PIVOT 
      (MAX(status) FOR userid IN, (',@ColumnPiVot,')) AS pivottable')
   PRINT @query
   exec sp_executesql  @query
```